How do I send parameters like role to next-auth at signup
I have what seems to be a conceptual doubt about where and how to implement user role logic in a next-auth app and which approach is the most conventional.
Namely when using something like this
providers: [
    Auth0Provider({
        clientId: env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
        issuer: env.AUTH0_ISSUER,
        profile(profile) {
            return {
                id: profile.sub,
                name: profile.name,
                email: profile.email,
                image: profile.picture,
                role: //HERE I CAN SET 
            } as User;
        },
    }),
],

This correctly sets up the role when hardcoded, the Prisma adapter is working too and I can get it all the way to the frontend with the session callback
callbacks: {
    session: ({ session, user }) => ({
        ...session,
        user: {
            ...session.user,
            id: user.id,
            role: user.role,
        },
    }),
},

What I don't understand is where to get this logic from, how can I send it to next-auth.
The only thing I can come up with is something like setting a cookie with the role, let's say I have two buttons one for customer signup and another for partner signup, before redirecting to /api/auth/signin I could set a cookie, but this is kind of ugly to do it next-js app router from the client side, and I seem to be missing something obvious here.
What is the most common/recommended approach for this? How can I pass the logic down to the options?

next-auth itself does not handle user roles directly; it provides the tools and callbacks necessary to integrate with your existing user role management system. The developer is responsible for implementing role management by fetching and assigning roles from the database. it's common practice to associate roles with users in your database but if you do not set up database for your app, next-auth stores the user in jwt. From role-based-access-control docs
Persisting the role will be different depending on the session strategy you’re using. If you don’t know which session strategy you’re using, then most likely you’re using JWT (the default one).

With JWT
When you don’t have a database configured, the role will be persisted
in a cookie, by using the jwt() callback. On sign-in, the role
property is exposed from the profile callback on the user object.
Persist the user.role value by assigning it to token.role. That’s it!

If you implement database, you have a User model with role property. If you want to tell next-auth to give access to certain roles, maybe "admin", you write a middleware and next-auth will handle it. for example:
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";
import { IUser } from "./backend/models/user";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

// https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#wrap-middleware
export default withAuth(
  function middleware(req) {
    // authorize roles
    const url = req?.nextUrl?.pathname;
    //`withAuth` augments your `Request` with the user's token.
    const user = req?.nextauth?.token?.user;

    if (url?.startsWith("/admin") && user?.role !== "admin") {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", req.url));
    }
  },
  {
    callbacks: {
      authorized: ({ token }) => !!token,
    },
  }
);

export const config = {
  // matcher is the route that we want to protect
  matcher: ["/admin/:path*"],
};

above middleware is designed to protect client-side routes/pages in a Next.js application.
If you want to protect server-side API routes or backend resources, you can write this middleware:
export const authorizeRoles = (...roles: string[]) => {
  return (req: NextRequest, event: any, next: any) => {
    if (!roles.includes(req.user.role)) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        {
          errMessage: `Access denied for (${req.user.role}) role`,
        },
        { status: 403 }
      );
    }

    return next();
  };
};


My question is where to determine role at signup, I can redirect to
/api/auth/signin and the the user will signup for the first time, but
I need to distinguish there between to types of users. Maybe something
like /api/auth/signin?user=partner or something like this, it is
specifically about the signup process, and where do I set whatever
param or something like that and where do I apply that logic at signup

the main logic of signup process is to get the credentials, validate the credentials and then save the user in database. You don't need to write separate backend logic for partner and customer signup processes. Once the user is saved in the database, you fetch the user data, including their role, in different parts of the application to manage access control and provide role-specific features.
but in front end, you can let users to choose which role to signup for example:
<div>
  <h1>Welcome!</h1>
  <p>Choose your signup option:</p>
  <button onClick={() => router.push('/signup?user=customer')}>Customer Signup</button>
  <button onClick={() => router.push('/signup?user=partner')}>Partner Signup</button>
</div>

this will route to signup with the user query parameter. in SignUpForm you can have this logic:
function SignupForm() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { user } = router.query; // Get the user type from the query parameter
  const [role, setRole] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user === 'partner' || user === 'customer') {
      setRole(user);
    } else {
      // Redirect to a default or error page if the role is invalid
      router.push('/');
    }
  }, [user, router]);
  ....

  // you write handle submit logic

  return  (
  // you write jsx here
 )


Thanks for the answer. My question is where to determine role at signup, I can redirect to /api/auth/signin and the the user will signup for the first time, but I need to distinguish there between to types of users. Maybe something like /api/auth/signin?user=partner or something like this, it is specifically about the signup process, and where do I set whatever param or something like that and where do I apply that logic at signup.

updated the answer

This seems to be with a custom signup page, is this correct? Can it be done with the default?

You need a user onboarding design I would say, rather than it being a technical question.
OAUTH SELF SIGNUP AND USER ATTRIBUTES
A self signup should execute in the context of an OAuth authorization code flow. You make an authorization request and the user selects a create account option. So in your app, you should only provide a login button. There is no need to have signup options or set cookies.
The signup user experience is managed by the authorization server. To add extra fields, such as a role, you would use the authorization server's customization features, such as in this Auth0 article.
User signup results in user accounts being created, containing attributes, which are saved to data sources. After signup, the user runs subsequent screens in the authorization server, eg to activate their account and complete their initial login. The user is then redirected back to the app, which then has access to any user attributes created.
GETTING USER ATTRIBUTES IN YOUR APP
When you use the OpenID Connect profile scope, your app can download claims associated to that scope from the OpenID Connect userinfo endpoint. To get custom user attributes back to your app, you should be able to follow the same approach by adding an additional scope.
Your app could use a custom scope, eg openid profile products, and you might include a role claim in the products scope. The extra scope gives you access to the role, in tokens or from the userinfo endpoint.
USER VERIFICATION AND TRUST LEVELS
A self signup form is often accompanied by some form of authentication. For customer users, you may not really know who they are, so you might just ask them to verify their email, then assign them a (default) customer role.
For partner users, you will set a role and partner ID that is likely to grant access to partner data. These fields are security sensitive and the authentication needs a partner level proof.
Some kind of administrator approval is typically used, so users may be precreated rather than using self sign up:

Partner administrators use an app that calls your API with a partner-level API credential. Your API creates a user account in Auth0, after which perhaps each user is sent an account activation email.

Or an out-of-band people process might be followed, where a partner occasionally asks your company to precreate particular users and someone at your company creates the partner user.


To use self sign up for partner users, they need to know some information to enter in the signup form, including a partner level proof.
For example, partner users might be given some kind of device that provides a time-based one-time password (TOTP) that they can enter in your signup form.
SUMMARY
User onboarding in OAuth is an intricate topic. The authorization server gives you building blocks, like user management APIs. Yet you still need to think through each concern, such as each category of user, to decide how to use the building blocks. Solutions tend to involve separation of concerns, but only straightforward code.
